# How to increment a MySQL timestamp in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

So I have a MYSQL timestampl that is generating values that are 4hours ahead of what they should be. How would i subtract 4hrs from the MySQL time stamp and display that?

Here's my current code

```
$mdate = date('F j, Y, g:i a',strtotime( $bm->date_added)); 
//$bm->dated_added returns the times stamp//
echo $mdate;
```

Thanks

Comment: That's a brutish solution that doesn't attempt to find out _why_ you have hours ahead. What timezone are you in? What timezone is your server set to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When supplied with a second argument, [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) will perform calculations based on this date:

```
$mdate = date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime('-4 hours', $bm->date_added));
```

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) can perform several calculations base on modifiers like these. Examples from the [manual](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
<?php
echo strtotime("now"), "\n";
echo strtotime("10 September 2000"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 day"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"), "\n";
echo strtotime("next Thursday"), "\n";
echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really figure out the root problem and fix it. Most likely you need to set MySQL's timezone to fit your own (or the server itself has the wrong date set).

That said, you can just subtract 14,400 seconds from the strtotime result.

```
$mdate = date('F j, Y, g:i a',strtotime($bm->date_added) - 14400);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the SUBTIME() function in your query if you cannot change the server time to reflect a appropriate timestamp

Answer (score 1):

SQL approach:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(the_timestamp, INTERVAL -4 HOURS)
```

This will return you the offset time